# Oracle equivalent to SQL function 'convert'

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

For e.g in SQL I have:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), mydate, 120)
CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), cost)
```

Is there an equivalent for these in Oracle?

Comment: Maybe CAST? http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/cast.php

Comment: What do they do?  I know the Oracle side but not up on sql server functions.

Comment: Data types of the columns involved would help.

Answer (score 8):

This in TSQL:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), mydate, 120)
```

...returns a string, so you should probably use [TO_CHAR](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php):

```
TO_CHAR(mydate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

You'd use [TO_DATE](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) if the value is not already an Oracle DATE data type, using the same format mask:

```
TO_DATE(mydate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

...or I would anyways, preferring explicit data type conversion when dealing with temporal data types.

---

This in TSQL:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),cost)
```

...needs to use the [CAST function](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/cast.php):

```
CAST(cost AS DECIMAL(18,2))
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to look at the [built-in functions for PLSQL](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/).

[`to_date('15/11/2010''dd/MM/yyyy')`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

and

[`to_number('1234.567','999.99')`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_number.php)